# Mockito ambiguous method call

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to stub out a method call, e.g.

```
when(amazonDynamoDBClient.batchWriteItem(anyObject())).thenReturn(batchWriteItemResultMock);
```

I get this error

```
Error:(198, 34) java: reference to batchWriteItem is ambiguous
  both method batchWriteItem(com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.BatchWriteItemRequest) in com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient and method batchWriteItem(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.WriteRequest>>) in com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient match
```

I can't see how this is ambiguous - the method signatures are different, i.e.

```
public BatchWriteItemResult batchWriteItem(BatchWriteItemRequest request) {
```

and

```
public BatchWriteItemResult batchWriteItem(Map<String, List<WriteRequest>> requestItems) {
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, is that `anyObject()` supposed to be a `Map` or a `BatchWriteItemRequest`?

Comment: I misread the 2nd signature - for some reason I was reading it as 2 parameters, a map and a list instead

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have two methods with the same name and return type, each with one parameter. So `anyObject()` matches both of them. That's why you get the `batchWriteItem is ambiguous` message.

You could use `Mockito.any(Class<T> type)` and `Mockito.anyMapOf(Class<K> keyClazz, Class<V> valueClazz)` to distinguish between them.

Docs for reference: [any](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any(java.lang.Class)), [anyMapOf](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyMapOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class))

Comment: doh - I misread the 2nd signature - thought there were 2 parameters, thanks

Comment: Note, I previously tried the any(BatchWriteItemResult.class) but ran into an unresolved method issue which is a different problem

Comment: @Bacon do you mean any(BatchWriteItem**Request**.class)?

Comment: Yeah - BatchWriteItemRequest.class

Comment: Why does it matter that there are multiple methods? Can't it just say regardless of the specific method?

Comment: @Goldname `any` matches literally any type you pass as argument, where as `anyMapOf` is specifically matching `Map`s with the given key types and value types.

Comment: I mean, in Mockito's perspective, why does it care whether or not your argument matches multiple functions?

Comment: @Goldname look at the method OP is calling: `.batchWriteItem(anyObject())`. Which one of the two methods `batchWriteItem(BatchWriteItemRequest request)` and `batchWriteItem(Map<String, List<WriteRequest>> requestItems)` should be mocked away? Mockito needs a way to tell which method to wire up.

Comment: It would make more sense to me if Mockito would just mock both. It only makes sense that way that any() would tell mockito to mock whichever method that is matching the argument

Comment: @Goldname It can't mock both, because those two methods might have completely different behaviour and side effects. Let's say method `a(SomeClass c)` calls some spied on component `Component` and method `a(SomeMap<K,V> m)` does not. It would be impossible to verify if `Component#someMethod` have actually been called, when it's not clear which one of those `a` methods is actually mocked. Remember, you mock *behaviour*, so it's important to know which method actually displays that exact behaviour. If the framework is not able to make such a distinction, it's useless.

Comment: @Goldname Although your suggestion with the generic `any()` might work. I can't verify it right now though.

Comment: I tried `when(classAObj.build(anyMap(), any(ClassB.class))).thenReturn("test")` but I am getting null for `classAObj.build()` with in the method being tested.

Answer (score 2):

For me, using `isA()` fixed the issue.

Docs : [IsA](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class))

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: Example:
`when(myService).myFunction(isA(String[].class), isA(HashMap.class))`