# Java ambiguous method error for Jdbc template

Tags: java, junit4, jdbctemplate, easymock

While trying to test a data access object implementation class, I am getting an error which says: "The method query(String, Object[], ResultSetExtractor, Class) is ambiguous for the type JdbcTemplateTestWrapper". In the line that throws the error, I am trying to use EasyMock matchers to match the arguments passed into the method "query" that gets called. Please can someone explain why I am getting this error? Note: the JdbcTemplateTestWrapper which was created for testing purposes extends JdbcTemplateWrapper.

The line that throws the error in my JUnit tests:
`expect(jdbcTemplate.query(EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject(),
         EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(tranList);`

The method call in my Data access object implementation class which needs the expectation:

```
tranList = (List<TransactionSummary>) jdbcTemplate.query(sqlStatement, 
            args, new RowMapperResultSetExtractor(mapper), 
            TransactionSummary.class);
```

The method "query" getting called in my JdbcTemplateTestWrapper class:

```
public <T> List<T> query(String sql, Object[] args, ResultSetExtractor extractor, Class<T> returnType) {
    List<T> list = null;

    try {
        list = (List<T>) jdbcOperations.query(sql, args, extractor);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problem retrieving data from AS400", 
                                    e);
    }

    return list;
}
```

The method "query" in JdbcTemplateWrapper which gets over-ridden by the one in JdbcTemplateTestWrapper:

```
public <T> List<T> query(String sql, Object[] args, ResultSetExtractor 
                      extractor, Class<T> returnType) {
    long queryStartTime = 0;
    long queryEndTime = 0;
    StringBuilder queryArgs = new StringBuilder();

    try {

        queryStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> results = (List<T>) super.query(sql, args, extractor);
        queryEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try{
            if(isLogSQLCalls() && ((queryEndTime - queryStartTime) > 
                    queryExecutionTime)){               
                //Uncomment following line to get the JDBC Call 
                       //message printed to tomcat window/tomcat log file
                //StringBuilder loggerInfo = buildLogMessage(sql, 
                      //args, queryStartTime, queryEndTime, 
                        //results.size());    
                for (Object object : args) {
                    queryArgs.append(object + " # ");
                }               
                updateAuditLogDao.logJDBCCall(sql, queryArgs, 
                      queryStartTime, queryEndTime, results.size(), 0);
                //Uncomment following line to get the JDBC Call 
                        //message printed to tomcat window/tomcat log file
                //LOGGER.info(loggerInfo); 
            }
        }catch(Exception exception){
            LOGGER.fatal(exception, exception);
        }
        return results;
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        queryEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try{
            if(isLogSQLCalls() && ((queryEndTime - queryStartTime) > 
                   queryExecutionTime)){                
                    updateAuditLogDao.logJDBCCall(sql, queryArgs, 
                              queryStartTime, queryEndTime, 0, 1);
            }
        }catch(Exception exception){
            LOGGER.fatal(exception, exception);
        }

        LOGGER.fatal(e, e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Problem retrieving data from AS400", 
                                    e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give the error?

Comment: Yes it is in the question. "The method query(String, Object[], ResultSetExtractor, Class) is ambiguous for the type JdbcTemplateTestWrapper". Thanks

Comment: How about posting the stack trace of the error

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
   when(jdbcTemplate.query(any(String.class), any(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.class)))
       .thenReturn(yourReturnObject);
```

From: [Mockito ambiguous method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842568/mockito-ambiguous-method-call)